# Separate statements in anonymous functions

Tags: lambda, elixir

I'm trying to write a simple function to turn a stream of words into title case. However, I'm hung up on restructuring the resulting tuple from `titlecase_once` and concatenating the results. In JavaScript I would use a semicolon to separate the statements, but I'm not sure what to do here.

```
Stream.cycle(~w{ red white blue })
  |> Stream.map(&({h,t} = String.Casing.titlecase_once(&1)) # How do we return `h <> t` here?
  |> Enum.take(7)
```

Comment: What output do you want for `fooBAR`? `Foobar` or `FooBAR`?

Comment: @Dogbert This is just a dummy snippet, so I don't especially care. Let's say `FooBAR` for consistency?

Comment: If `Foobar` is fine, couldn't you just use `String.capitalize/1`?

Comment: Yes, that would work! Thanks, I'm still getting to grips with the stdlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like that? It takes two maps but it's more clear I think.

```
Stream.cycle(~w{ red white blue })
|> Stream.map(&(String.Casing.titlecase_once(&1)))
|> Stream.map(fn({h,t}) -> h <> t end)
|> Enum.take(7)
```

Or using one function:

```
Stream.cycle(~w{ red white blue })
|> Stream.map(fn(word) ->
  {h,t} = String.Casing.titlecase_once(word)
  h <> t
end)
|> Enum.take(7)
```

Or the same but in one line:

```
Stream.cycle(~w{ red white blue })
|> Stream.map(fn(word) -> {h,t} = String.Casing.titlecase_once(word); h <> t end)
|> Enum.take(7)
```

Comment: I like this for short things, but it does feel a little silly that I can just concat and return the item in the first map. Is there an idiomatic way to separate statements in Elixir or is it specifically disallowed? I have found zero documentation on this.

Comment: I can't come up with a sane way to do it if you want to use specifically the short function form. You could put it on two lines with the usual function form, but if that's too long as well, then I am not sure.

Comment: That's fine, I wasn't trying to specifically use the short form. If it works in the long form on multiple lines, can I see a sample? (I have just been trying to do this in `iex` thus far)

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think there may be a way to do it in a more short way. Let's wait for other answers.